Can I put multiple stranded wires into a single WAGO terminal?
Can I put multiple stranded wires into a single WAGO terminal, provided that the cross-sectional area of any one of the wires is more than the required minimum (0.2 mm2), and the sum of the cross-sectional areas of all the wires is less than the required maximum (4 mm2)?


In lieu of any official instruction from Wago, I would suggest twisting the two wires together, at a minimum.

At least in USA's NEC, you have to follow the instructions of the devices you're using to maintain compliance with code and insurance underwriting.
The Wago instructions available at https://www.wago.com/us/221-handling-instructions show only one wire going into each slot. The words with the pictures say:

Push lever up and insert wire. After wire is inserted, push lever down. Repeat steps 1 and 2 for additional connection.

Following these instructions, put one wire in, flip the lever down, then repeat on additional slots. No mention of multiple wires in one slot, only one wire.
Putting multiple wires in one slot is not following the instructions. Such could get you a denied insurance claim after a fire. Insurance companies can be like that.
I deduce by your use of mm2 that you're not in the USA proper and may have another code body in your jurisdiction. But there may be the same rule about following the device's instructions. You should check your local jurisdiction to see if they are also "follow the instructions"-centric.

Multiple wires in a Wago connector is not recommended. The clamp mechanism inside could clamp to one wire firmly and not the other one. This can lead to the lesser clamped wire able to pull out of the connector.
Twisting together stranded wires may work - however there can be great variability in how easy it is twist together wires of different styles - expecially in the short strip length used on wires inserted into these connectors.
